# Consulta SQlite en tkinter - python

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

gente que tal , hay manera de sumar todo lo que tengo en una columna llamada precio y me lo muestre en un label?

estoy intentando en una ventana mostrar el efectivo que hay en "caja" necesitaría que sume todos los valores de las ventas hechas y me lo muestre

```
class Efectivo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.titulo = "Dinero"
        self.icono = "Proyecto/Iconos/Registradora.ico"
        self.resizable = False
        self.color = "#83D6A8"

    def Inicio(self):
        # Iniciar ventana
        ventana_efectivo = Tk()
        self.ventana_efectivo = ventana_efectivo
        # Titulo
        ventana_efectivo.title(self.titulo)
        # Tamaño de la ventana
        ox, oy = ventana_efectivo.winfo_screenwidth(
        )/5, ventana_efectivo.winfo_screenheight()/5
        ventana_efectivo.geometry("=500x250+%d+%d" % (ox--150, oy--30))
        # Bloquear el tamaño
        if (self.resizable):
            ventana_efectivo.resizable(1, 1)
        else:
            ventana_efectivo.resizable(0, 0)
        # Agregar Icono
        ventana_efectivo.iconbitmap(self.icono)
        # Configuraciones
        self.ventana_efectivo.config(
            bg=self.color
        )
        #### CONTENIDO ####
        Label(ventana_efectivo, text="Efectivo en caja:",
              font=("Arial", 26, "bold"), bg="#83D6A8").place(x = 90, y = 20)

        marco = LabelFrame(ventana_efectivo)
        marco.config(
            width = 400,
            height = 100,
            bg = "#83D6A8",
            bd = 5
        )
        marco.place(x =50, y = 80)
        ventana_efectivo.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Sería precio x cantidad o precio es el total ya?

Comment: nono precio ya es el total del articulo vendido

Comment: tendria que sumar todos los valores de precio y mostrarlos en la ventana

Comment: lei por ahi que decia SELECT SUM para sumar pero nose como ejecutarla con sqlite y tekinter

Comment: Se entendio   ? es una consulta sql

Comment: @FJSevilla Se entendio ?

Comment: Si, si tu columna es de tipo numérico, SUM es la respuesta. ¿Sumarías toda la columna de la tabla sin más o aplicarías algún filtro?

Comment: pero como lo muestro? intento mostrarlo en un label y no me deja 

        db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre)
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT SUM(Precio) FROM Ventas")
        c.close()

esta es la consulta sql pero como hago para mostrar el resultado en un label?

Answer (score 1):

Si quioeres sumar todos los valores de la columna la consulta es simplemente:

> SELECT SUM(Precio) FROM Ventas

Ten en cuenta que si usas fetchall te retornará una lista de la forma:

```
[(suma,)]
```

Si usas una variable `tkinter.DoubleVar` puedes pasarla como tal:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.db_path = "file::memory:?cache=shared"
        self.total_ventas = tk.DoubleVar(self)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.total_ventas).pack(expand=True)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Obtener total de ventas", 
            command=self.calcular_total_ventas
            ).pack(expand=True)

    def calcular_total_ventas(self):
        suma = self.make_query("SELECT SUM(Precio) FROM Ventas")
        self.total_ventas.set(suma)
        
    def make_query(self, query, params=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            data = cursor.execute(query, params).fetchall()
            cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    with sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ventas (id INTEGUER, Precio DECIMAL)"
            )
        cursor.executemany(
            "INSERT INTO Ventas VALUES(?, ?)", 
            ((1, 12.3), (2, 3.8), (2, 15))
            )
        cursor.close()
    db.close()
    

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Si usas una `StringVar` o asignas al `Label` el texto directamente mediante el atributo `text`, debes obtener el valor y convertir a `str`:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.db_path = "file::memory:?cache=shared"
        self.total_ventas = tk.StringVar(self)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.total_ventas).pack(expand=True)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Obtener total de ventas", 
            command=self.calcular_total_ventas
            ).pack(expand=True)

    def calcular_total_ventas(self):
        res = self.make_query("SELECT SUM(Precio) FROM Ventas")
        suma = f"{res[0][0]:.2f}" 
        self.total_ventas.set(suma)
        
    def make_query(self, query, params=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            data = cursor.execute(query, params).fetchall()
            cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    with sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ventas (id INTEGUER, Precio DECIMAL)"
            )
        cursor.executemany(
            "INSERT INTO Ventas VALUES(?, ?)", 
            ((1, 12.3), (2, 3.8), (2, 15))
            )
        cursor.close()
    db.close()
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Ten cuidado con usar floats (`DECIMAL`) para almacenar datos monetarios en una BD, son susceptibles de sufrir errores por representación en coma flotante y puedes perder o ganar dinero inexplicablemente...